# CAKEPHP - Issue with authorization, login page doesnt work

Tags: cakephp

I wrote a little script in CakePHP, but at the moment I have got a little issue.
I wrote login user Controller

```
//Login
public function login() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'tasks']);
        }
        //Bad Login
        $this->Flash->error('Incorrect Login or Password');
    }
}
```

Login CTP:

```
<div class="index large-4 medium-4 large-offset-4 medium-offset-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
        <?= $this->Form->create(); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('email'); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('password', array('type' => 'password')); ?>
            <center><?= $this->Form->submit('Zaloguj', array('class' => 'button')); ?></center>
        <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the APPController (part which is resposible of Authorization):

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'autheticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ]
        ]);
}
```

I tried to do:

```
        dump($this->Auth->user('email'));
        die();
```

But on my screen I have got 'null'.

Someone has got any idea what I did wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: You should debug in login function before identify() and after identify() then you may realize what the problem is !!!

Comment: I found a reason... :)

"autheticate" there is no 'n'